# Highlight Unmatched words in angular using pipes

Tags: angular, pipe

I want to highlight the unmatched string in search instead of matching one. Although I have code to highlight the matched one but struggling to make selection to unmatched one like google search doing in angular

I have tried in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highlight-pipe-1mqlqt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

It only highlighting matched string, I want to highlight other than matched string. like google search

[image]

Comment: You can actually take it the other way. Instead of highlighting the matched words, you can "lowlight" them. So each div would have the gray background, and those with the "lowlight" class would have a transparent background.

Comment: you can modify the existing highlight pipe to achieve the desired result

Comment: This isn't what pipes are for. Use a directive instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to the code you made available in stackblitz, you could do it this way:

```
transform(value: any, args: any): any {
  if (!args) {
    return value;
  }

  const re = new RegExp(args, 'gi');

  // split the string using the input term
  const parts = value.split(re);
  
  // highlight "non-matched" parts
  const highlighted = parts.map(
    (p) => `<span class='highlight-text'>${p}</span>`
  );
  
  // join highlighted parts with the input term 
  const joined = highlighted.join(args);
  return joined;
}
```

Short version:

```
transform(value: any, args: any): any {
  if (!args) {
    return value;
  }
  // Match in a case insensitive maneer
  const re = new RegExp(args, 'gi');

  return value.split(re).map(
    (p) => `<span class='highlight-text'>${p}</span>`
  ).join(args);
}
```